# Remove small compose-identifier from List with Lambdas

Tags: java, spring-boot, lambda, stream, identifier

I need to remove an specifics 'ids' from a list.
Explaining myself better, I have a list of 'Documents' that contains compound `Strings`, which are `identifiers`.
These `identifiers` are made up of a pair of `Integers` separated by a "-".
The idea is to remove from that list of `identifiers`, all those that contain the same first part of the `String` AND keep only the largest of them. That is, if I have a list of 'Documents' with the following output:

```
"documentId": "521-1"
"documentId": "521-2"
"documentId": "32-2"
"documentId": "112-6"
"documentId": "112-11"
"documentId": "112-2"
```

The result should be:

```
"documentId": "521-2"
"documentId": "112-11"
"documentId": "32-2"
```

I have tried to do it with streams but I don't see the way. I go through the list but since they are compound `identifiers` I don't know how to make the comparisons nor how to keep the smallest of them.

My pseudo-code, which not works:

```
    object.getDocuments().stream().reduce((a, b)->{                     
if(a.getFirstPart().equals(b.getFirstPart())){
        //Then I should remove the small secondPart                 
    } return b;});
```

Many thanks

Comment: If you want to remove something, you should try filter on the stream.

Comment: sorry but no, filter can't allow use Predicates and i need to use it @JustanotherJavaprogrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Note that it isn't robust against invalid data.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] ids = {"521-1",
                "521-2",
                "32-2",
                "112-6",
                "112-11",
                "112-2"
        };
        List<String> result = Arrays.stream(ids).collect(Collectors.toMap(
                s -> s.split("-")[0], s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("-")[1]), Math::max
        )).entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + "-" + e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```